# Install magento2 on a sub folder

Tags: magento2, installation

I am trying to install magento 2 in a sub folder of already installed magento 2, when I try to access sub folder, it takes me to 404 page for the root magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

404 error occur when system is unable to find location/path of folder/file
if you are using ubuntu open terminal in sub-folder and run this will show you the path then use that path to access that folder

```
pwd
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Update your `.htaccess` in parent `root` folder

For example

```
-Magento_site1/
    - app/
    - design/
    - Magento_site2/
           - app
           -design
           - .... 
    -....
    -.htaccess <-update this
```

Like this

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       #..
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} "/Magento_site2/" 
       RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
```